# Comparing PrevProps in componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to detect when a prop has changed inside `componentDidUpdate` of a mounted component. I have a test (`refreshData` in the code below) that is working fine. Is it possible to SOMEHOW pass props in a way that aren't detected by `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)`?

In component.js:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

    //works fine
    if ( this.props.refreshData !== prevProps.refreshData ) {
        if ( this.props.refreshData )
            this.refreshData();
    }

    //these two arent calling
    if ( this.props.selectedCountries !== prevProps.selectedCountries ) {
        if ( this.props.selectedCountries )
            console.log('updated selected countries');
    }

    if ( this.props.selectedLocations !== prevProps.selectedLocations ) {
        console.log('updated selected locations');
    }

}
```

and in App.js passing the props like:

```
selectLocation = (id, type, lng, lat, polydata, name, clear = false) => {

  //console.log(type);
  //console.log(lng);
  //console.log(lat);
  //console.log(polydata);

  let selectedType = 'selected' + type;
  let previousState = [];

  if (clear) {
    this.setState({
      selectedCountries: [],
      selectedLocations: [],
      selectedServices: [],
      selectedPoints: [],
      mapCenter: [lng, lat],
      locationGeoCoords: [polydata]
    })
    previousState.push(id);

  } else {

    previousState = this.state[selectedType];
    if (previousState.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      //push id
      previousState.push(id);

    } else {
      //remove id
      var index = previousState.indexOf(id)
      previousState.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  if (type === "Countries") {

    this.setState({
      selectedCountries: previousState,
      refreshData: true,
    })
  } else if (type === "Locations") {
    this.setState({
      selectedLocations: previousState,
      refreshData: true
    })
  } else if (type === "Points") {
    this.setState({
      selectedPoints: previousState,
      refreshData: true
    })
  }


}


render() {
  return (

    <component
      selectedCountries={this.state.selectedCountries}
      selectedLocations={this.state.selectedLocations}
      refreshData={this.state.refreshData} />
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're not actually properly updating the array - if you assign previousState to this.state[whatever] then mutate it, you're actually mutating the original array too. You'd need to do something like previousState = [].concat(this.state[selected type]

Comment: Sorry on my phone or I'd write a proper answer and explanation, hopefully that's enough to go by for you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hi :) as noted in my comment, the issue is in your App.js file - you are mutating an array. In other words, when you THINK you are creating a new array of selected countries to pass down, you are actually updating the original array, and so when you go to do a comparison you are comparing the two exact same arrays ALWAYS.

Try updating your App.js like so -

```js
selectLocation = (id, type, lng, lat, polydata, name, clear = false) => {

  //console.log(type);
  //console.log(lng);
  //console.log(lat);
  //console.log(polydata);

  let selectedType = 'selected' + type;
  let previousState = [];

  if (clear) {
    this.setState({
      selectedCountries: [],
      selectedLocations: [],
      selectedServices: [],
      selectedPoints: [],
      mapCenter: [lng, lat],
      locationGeoCoords: [polydata]
    })
    previousState.push(id);

  } else {

    previousState = [].concat(this.state[selectedType]);
    if (previousState.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      //push id
      previousState.push(id);

    } else {
      //remove id
      var index = previousState.indexOf(id)
      previousState.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  if (type === "Countries") {

    this.setState({
      selectedCountries: previousState,
      refreshData: true,
    })
  } else if (type === "Locations") {
    this.setState({
      selectedLocations: previousState,
      refreshData: true
    })
  } else if (type === "Points") {
    this.setState({
      selectedPoints: previousState,
      refreshData: true
    })
  }


}


render() {
  return (

    <component
      selectedCountries={this.state.selectedCountries}
      selectedLocations={this.state.selectedLocations}
      refreshData={this.state.refreshData} />
  }
}
```

The only difference is the line where you set `previousState` - I updated it to  be

`previousState = [].concat(this.state[selectedType]);`

By adding the `[].concat` I am effectively creating a NEW array each time and so then when you apply your changes to the array via `push`/`splice` you will be only modifying the NEW array. Then the comparison will work properly once you pass it down as props :)

For your reading interest, I found a post that talks about this a bit: https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c

Comment: no problem :) tbh I'm sure @sushanth would have also given you similar advice, I had the unfair advantage that you updated your question with app.js a bit later on 

Comment: [].concat(this.state[selectedType]) did the job for me! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

`selectedCountries` and `selectedLocations` are array objects. The reference of it never changes. Instead check for the length.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

    if ( this.props.refreshData !== prevProps.refreshData ) {
        if ( this.props.refreshData )
            this.refreshData();
    }

    if ( this.props.selectedCountries.length > prevProps.selectedCountries.length ) {
        if ( this.props.selectedCountries )
            console.log('updated selected countries');
    }

    if ( this.props.selectedLocations.length > prevProps.selectedLocations.length ) {
        console.log('updated selected locations');
    }
}
```

In the code snippet above, you seem to be making changes to `this.state` directly. State should be immutable. Always make sure, you `concat` to add and `filter` to delete the elements as they create a new array instead of mutating the original array in the state. I would do something in these lines.

Also it is a good practice to capitalize the component name.

```js
selectLocation = (id, type, lng, lat, polydata, name, clear = false) => {
        //console.log(type);
        //console.log(lng);
        //console.log(lat);
        //console.log(polydata);

        let selectedType = "selected" + type;
        let previousState = [];
        let updatedData = [];

        if (clear) {
          this.setState({
            selectedCountries: [],
            selectedLocations: [],
            selectedServices: [],
            selectedPoints: [],
            mapCenter: [lng, lat],
            locationGeoCoords: [polydata]
          });
        } else {
          const data = this.state[selectedType];
          if (data.indexOf(id) === -1) {
            //push id
            updatedData = [...data, id];
          } else {
            updatedData = data.filter((value) => value !== id);
          }
        }

        if(type) {
          this.setState({
            [selectedType]: updatedData,
            refreshData: true
          });
        }
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <component
            selectedCountries={this.state.selectedCountries}
            selectedLocations={this.state.selectedLocations}
            refreshData={this.state.refreshData}
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: But they are getting passed from app.js state to component.js as props. So they would be props in comp.js no? Either way I tried the following and no go....

        if ( this.state.selectedCountries !== prevState.selectedCountries ) {
            if ( this.props.selectedCountries )
                console.log('updated selected countries');
        }

        if ( this.state.selectedLocations !== prevState.selectedLocations ) {
            console.log('updated selected locations');
        }

Comment: My bad. Check the updated post. As they point to the same reference the condition you have will always evaluate to true

Comment: Ugh this is a great answer but still didnt work for me :(

Comment: How is it that you are adding new items to the array ?

Comment: Using setState in App.js nothing crazy

Comment: It is hard to say without taking a look at the code that sets the state

Comment: I appreciate your help I just updated my question with the whole function that is setting state in App.js. I was really hoping it was something in that ;)

Answer (score 1):

did you make sure that the props of locations & countries are actually changing? If yes, the following code should work:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.selectedCountries.length !== prevProps.selectedCountries.length) {
    console.log("updated selected countries");
  }

  if (this.props.selectedLocations.length !== prevProps.selectedLocations.length) {
    console.log("updated selected locations");
  }
}
```

I created a fiddle for showcasing the effect here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/o580n8lnv5

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very issue. My solution was to send downstream to child components a *clone* of the state in question. This way when the state changes in `App.js` again, it will not affect the copy of the state passed down to children since those children were given a *clone*. In the previous props passed to `async componentDidUpdate (prevProps)` in child components, `prevProps` will be the clone that was originally handed down, and current props will be the most recent state changes made in `App.js`, which again is a clone, but prev and current props will be different.

Below is snipppet from `App.render()`, notice the value assign to the `filter` attribute, namely a clone the portion of the state in question:

```
...
<Routes onCategorySelect={this.handleCategorySelect}
                onCategoryUnselect={this.handleCategoryUnselect}
                onRouteLoad={this.handleRouteLoad} filter={this.cloneFilter(savedState.filter)}
                updatedDimension={this.state.updatedDimension}/>
...
```

And this is the `componentDidUpdate()` of the child component:

```
async componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (this.props.filter !== prevProps.filter && this.props.updatedDimension !== this.dimension) {
      await this.updateChart()
    }
  }
```